# C# - Refresh WPF RichTextBox during a loop

Tags: c#, refresh, richtextbox

I'm new learner in C# and i have a simple problem.

I do classic loop of 15 iterations with a Threat.Sleep of 3 secondes in each ones and inside this loop at each iteration i'm addind text to my RichTextBox.
BUT the text only appear at the end of the 15 iterations of 3 secondes ! :(

I want the text to be added at each iteration in the loop :) Is there a way to do that ?

Thank you for helping :)

AMIGA RULEZ

Comment: use async + `await Task.Deley(t)` instead `Thread.Sleep` ...

Comment: Thank You for your fast answer Selvin, Task.delay(3000) do the same. In fact if i do 2000 iterations of 1 line of text at each iteration. The text in RTB appear all at the end of the 2000 iterations. Timer or not inside the loop :)

Comment: Thanks again i tried more today and you teached me the async concept, that was my problem and it's solved with that !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this code and it worked.
When i press the button, the RTB adds the word "hello" each 3 seconds.

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += "hello";
            await Task.Delay(3000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Best and complete answer i followed many courses about C# and never seen this async concept, that was my problem thankd a lot for the full code and your answer. now all is working well ! Best regards

Answer (score 1):

`Thread.Sleep` will block the current thread. When a thread is blocked it cannot do anything else. So if it is the UI thread it cannot re-render the UI until the thread is unblocked. Because of this it is recommended to *never block the UI thread*.

A workaround is to use `Task.Delay` and async/await instead. Internally this will cause your code to be rewritten to a state machine. In principle transforming it to something like the following pseudo code

```
int i = 0;
timer = new Timer(TimerCallback, period: 3s);
timer.Start();
...
public void TimerCallback(){
    if(i >= 16){
        timer.Stop();
        return;
    }
    richTextBox1.Text += "hello";
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot i can't check the flag because my problem was not with the timer it was the async but thanks for this peace of code to make a nice timer ! it's helpfull for me anyway.